# Export as CSV after using for loop in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, csv, classification, for-loop

I'm trying to use the for-loop function for a supervised classification over several dates. I have trouble exporting the accuracy metrics that are useful to me in a single CSV file. With my code I can export the data for each day separately. But I would like to have a CSV file containing all the dates for which the images have been classified. Please help me. Here is the code:

```
//Can be converted to import records
var Bagre = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.FeatureCollection(
        [ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Polygon(
                [[[-0.9131136144573282, 11.80001340655708],
                  [-0.9131136144573282, 11.44960967007124],
                  [-0.4901399816448282, 11.44960967007124],
                  [-0.4901399816448282, 11.80001340655708]]], null, false),
            {
              "system:index": "0"
            })]),
    other = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.FeatureCollection(
        [ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.5993166173870157, 11.584173738244099]),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "0"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.7167329992229532, 11.6124239897709]),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "1"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.7263460363323282, 11.676312799623682]),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "2"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.6569948400432657, 11.641343901167035]),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "3"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.6734743322307657, 11.580137754769975]),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "4"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.7435121740276407, 11.584846396491287]),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "5"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.7874574865276407, 11.531701414565942]),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "6"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.8286562169963907, 11.580137754769975]),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "7"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.8149233068401407, 11.635963680007837]),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "8"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.7950105871135782, 11.61645950650287]),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "9"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.6789674962932657, 11.487294094934224]),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "10"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.6466951574260782, 11.474508871642358]),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "11"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.6082430089885782, 11.54919328080972]),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "12"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.5828371251995157, 11.463068970402034]),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "13"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.6391420568401407, 11.603680169832181]),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "14"
            })]),
    water = /* color: #0b4a8b */ee.FeatureCollection(
        [ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.5615511144573282, 11.487294094934224]),
            {
              "landcover": 1,
              "system:index": "0"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.5993166173870157, 11.499405876960067]),
            {
              "landcover": 1,
              "system:index": "1"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.6260957921917032, 11.51824539131339]),
            {
              "landcover": 1,
              "system:index": "2"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.6487550939495157, 11.533719762462855]),
            {
              "landcover": 1,
              "system:index": "3"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.6762209142620157, 11.544484039481423]),
            {
              "landcover": 1,
              "system:index": "4"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.6913271154338907, 11.537083643381099]),
            {
              "landcover": 1,
              "system:index": "5"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.7050600255901407, 11.524300681517477]),
            {
              "landcover": 1,
              "system:index": "6"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.7290926183635782, 11.549866023115023]),
            {
              "landcover": 1,
              "system:index": "7"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.7647981847698282, 11.570047541254711]),
            {
              "landcover": 1,
              "system:index": "8"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.7723512853557657, 11.586864361519334]),
            {
              "landcover": 1,
              "system:index": "9"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.6666078771526407, 11.539101952582197]),
            {
              "landcover": 1,
              "system:index": "10"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.5855837072307657, 11.491331413449927]),
            {
              "landcover": 1,
              "system:index": "11"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.5512514318401407, 11.512862801646012]),
            {
              "landcover": 1,
              "system:index": "12"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.5519380773479532, 11.482583816929104]),
            {
              "landcover": 1,
              "system:index": "13"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-0.5759706701213907, 11.486621202893533]),
            {
              "landcover": 1,
              "system:index": "14"
            })]);

var Domain = Bagre;

var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2");

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var gcp = other.merge(water);
var gcp_random = gcp.randomColumn();
var trainingGcp = gcp_random.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', 0.7));
var validationGcp = gcp_random.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', 0.7));

// List the years, months, and dates
var years = [2021];
var months = [1,1,1,1,1,1];
var days1 = [1,6,11,16,21,26];
var i;
var j;
for (i = 0; i<years.length;i++){
  for(j = 0; j<months.length;j++){
    var dayOfInterest = ee.Date(years[i] + "-" + months[j]  + "-" + days1[j]);
    var loop = S2
    .filter(ee.Filter.date(dayOfInterest, dayOfInterest.advance(1, 'day')))
    .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(Domain))
    .map(maskS2clouds)
    .select('B.*')
    .median()
    .clip(Domain);

// Extract Digital Numbers of pixels in training polygons
    var training = loop.sampleRegions({
      collection: trainingGcp,
      properties: ['landcover'],
      scale: 10,
      tileScale: 16,
    });
    
// Train a classifier.
    var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(100)
    .train({
      features: training,  
      classProperty: 'landcover',
      inputProperties: loop.bandNames()
    });
    
// Classify the satellite image
        var classified = loop.classify(classifier);

/* Accuracy Assessment*/
    var test = classified.sampleRegions({
    collection: validationGcp,
    properties: ['landcover'],
    scale: 10,
    tileScale: 16,
    });
    var testConfusionMatrix = test.errorMatrix('landcover', 'classification');

// Export accuracy assessment metrics as CSV
    var fc = ee.FeatureCollection([
    ee.Feature(null, {
    'Producers Accuracy': testConfusionMatrix.producersAccuracy().get([1,-1]).multiply(100),
    'Consumers Accuracy': testConfusionMatrix.consumersAccuracy().get([0,1]).multiply(100),
    'Overall Accuracy': testConfusionMatrix.accuracy().multiply(100),
    'Kappa coefficient': testConfusionMatrix.kappa().multiply(100),
    'Days': dayOfInterest.format('YYYY-MM-dd')
    })
    ]);
    Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: fc,
    description: 'Bagre_Area_Sq_Km' + "_" + years[i] + "-" + months[j]  + "-" + days1[j],
    folder: 'earthengine',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
    selectors:['Days','Overall Accuracy', 'Producers Accuracy', 'Consumers Accuracy', 'Kappa coefficient']
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by saving all the features inside an `ee.List` and then casting that list into a `ee.FeatureCollection`. For that, you need to create an empty list before the `for` loops and create an auxiliary variable `aux`. Then, instead of exporting each `ee.Feature` as an `ee.FeatureCollection`, save it inside the list. Finally, after the loops have ended you should cast the list into a `ee.FeatureCollection` and export it.
As a small piece of advice, I strongly suggest you use `map` instead of `for` to perform the loops, since `map` is the recommended function to make loops in the server-side. Using the `map` function can also simplify some parts of the code, since mapping over an `ee.List` will automatically organize the results into an `ee.List`.

```
// Part before the for loops
// Start empty list
var expList = ee.List([]);
// Start aux counter
var aux = 0;

// Final part of the for loops
// Export accuracy assessment metrics as CSV
    var fc = 
    ee.Feature(null, {
    'Producers Accuracy': testConfusionMatrix.producersAccuracy().get([1,-1]).multiply(100),
    'Consumers Accuracy': testConfusionMatrix.consumersAccuracy().get([0,1]).multiply(100),
    'Overall Accuracy': testConfusionMatrix.accuracy().multiply(100),
    'Kappa coefficient': testConfusionMatrix.kappa().multiply(100),
    'Days': dayOfInterest.format('YYYY-MM-dd')
    });
expList = expList.insert(aux,fc);
aux = aux+1;

// After the for loops
// Create FeatureCollection from list with features
var exportFC = ee.FeatureCollection(expList);

// Take a look at the console
print('exportFC', exportFC);

Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: exportFC,
    description: 'Bagre_Area_Sq_Km' + "_" + "all",
    folder: 'earthengine',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
    selectors:['Days','Overall Accuracy', 'Producers Accuracy', 'Consumers Accuracy', 'Kappa coefficient']
    });
```